# CURL vs Apache-HttpClient : variance in size of data received

Tags: rest, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using 2 agents to consume a REST webservice : Apache HttpClient and CURL.
Both the clients receive different size of data for the same REST webservice. Moreover the CURL is receiving inconsistent amount of bytes all the time while the Apache HttpClient is consistent.
Below is the access log snippet with number to bytes received.

```
"POST <<url>> HTTP/1.1" 200 10083053 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)" 
"POST <<url>> HTTP/1.1" 200 10083053 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)" 
"POST <<url>> HTTP/1.1" 200 10083053 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)" 

"POST <<url>> HTTP/1.1" 200 10128377 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
"POST <<url>> HTTP/1.1" 200 10128674 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
"POST <<url>> HTTP/1.1" 200 8192 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

What could be the problem with CURL receiving inconsistent amount of bytes?

Comment: I would first point the finger at the rest service attempting to mess with cURL, do you see the same output when you give it a alternate User-Agent like `curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" [URL]`?

Comment: Hi @JasonSperske - How can the service mess a call only from cURL and not from Apache-HttpClient? This is the entire client String logged : 
curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"

Comment: services that mess with cURL usually just sniff for the default cURL User Agent.  Apache-HttpClient is much less popular, but then this might not be it (it's just where I'd start)

Comment: cURL and libcURL are built into a lot of web scraping code, so blocking it is rather common

Comment: @JasonSperske - Any particular settings in server that could hamper  service for cURL and libcURL that you know?

Comment: dump the wire for both clients... http://superuser.com/questions/291424/how-do-you-display-post-data-with-curl   https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html